# Tumblr theme coding: display different post types on different sections on index page

Tags: post, types, tumblr

Is there a way to display different post types on different sections on tumblr in way so:

1. different sections are not in the same loop
   e.g. 
    Section 1
   {block:posts}{only photos}{/block:posts}
   html stuff here, bla bla bla on the page
   {block:posts}{only text posts}{/block:posts}
2. loops show content depending on the type but not on the count in the queue/list of all posts, i.e. to query only certain post type and show only its results irrespective of post position in the list of all posts.
   3.css displaying and hiding based on putting {PostType} in class not an option because:

   - the page will load different types based on number of displayable posts option, and /bad
   - will be a page of full hidden content duplicates. /bad
     I have found this post so far on quora but it lacks some functionality/ not an option. link: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-hide-certain-post-types-from-the-tumblr-front-page
     Actually if there is a way to bypass the counting of the hidden posts toward the number of posts in a page, it might be a solution.
     Any ideas?

Comment: Simplest way: simply tag your posts with some tag that groups them together irrespective of post type or content. You can than easily build pages that link to these posts (your.tumblr.com/tagged/sometag etc). Complex way: build an application which requests content via the api. This will allow you similar control, but you will have to write alot of code. If you want your index page to only show certain posts this is achievable but in my experience generally via a hack.

Comment: Your first point is a viable way of doing it. You would have `{block:Posts}{block:Photo} ... {/block:Photo}{/block:Posts}` and only photo posts would show up. You can continue this with all post types.